# How to answer the apology

Tags: phrase-request, politeness

Imagine a situation where you clash someone on a footpath, and that person apologizes. Now how should you answer when such a trivial mistake has happened?

The only thing that comes to my mind is **"no problem"**, but, I guess that's not good enough (it doesn't seem rude but it's not that much polite).

Is it right to just say **"my fault"**?!

Comment: You'll find many suitable (and unsuitable) answers [here](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-appropriate-responses-to-someone-saying-Im-sorry), [here](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/how-could-i-reply-to-sorry.661527/), [here](http://drallisonanswers.com/2015/03/23/3-ways-to-respond-to-an-apology-besides-its-okay/), .... . I don't think saying _my fault_ is polite, unless it can actually  be conceived as your fault.

Comment: What do you mean "clash" someone? Do you mean you bump into someone? Because "clash" suggests a more violent encounter.

Comment: @Fard Wow, very useful resources, especially the second one, thanks.

Comment: @Robusto I have no idea whether it's the right word. I just meant to say you and someone hit each other accidentally.

Comment: What dialect?  I have an impression that a British speaker might say "Not at all", but this would sound a little unusual in American English.

Comment: I don't think this is off-topic as primarily opinion-based. This question is not asking "what is the one best thing to say?" - it's asking for some guidance on how to be polite. I think we can help, even if there are some regional differences on the most commonly used phrase.

Comment: @NateEldredge I often say "Not at all" in this sort of circumstance.  Maybe I'm unusual though.  (Native AmE speaker)

Comment: @mok Is the other person actually at fault in your scenario? If you were equally at fault then you would likely respond with a comment that apologizes in turn.  If the other person was at fault (even though it's only a minor mistake) then a comment that forgives them would be best.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. I think the links @Fard provided provide the most comprehensive answers to my question, and I would accept it as the answer if it was posted as an answer.

Comment: You can answer your own question, you know!

Comment: @mok I wouldn't use any of those suggestions in the link in the situation which you describe. You might offend the person! See my post for why :-)

Answer (score 6):

Usually, when we bump into people or tread on each others toes or something like that, both people tend to say sorry. A normal exchange would be like this:

a: Sorry!

b: Sorry!

Don't say *No problem* or *never mind* or anything like that. The person is saying *sorry* to be polite. They probably don't feel that they have done anything wrong. They just want to be friendly and polite. Saying sorry is just a way to show that we are friendly. If you say *never mind* or *no worries* then  there's a  chance that you will annoy the other person. This is because you may sound as if you feel they *should* be sorry. They may not feel that they should be for such a trivial thing. So, just say: *Sorry!* And smile.

This is definitely the situation in the UK. I believe it is similar in the US.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for, especially these parts "...They just want to be friendly and polite" and "... you may sound as if you feel they should be sorry." .

Comment: +1. Good point; replying with _No problem_ etc may sound snobbish.

Comment: You can also say "Excuse me" instead of "Sorry!" I use the Italian [scusi](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scusi) sometimes and no-one blinks an eye at it (one of the advantages of speaking a language that steals from other languages). You can say almost anything brief and apologetic and your tone of voice and demeanor will make it OK. I haven't once encountered a person that got offended at "no worries" and I have seen someone get offended at "SORRY!" because of the tone.

Comment: @ColleenV Yes, agreed! It's the apologetic and friendly aspect that's important, not the exact words.

Answer (score 5):

I would say "No worries" or "No problem." or "No problem. Don't worry."

Comment: No worries would probably be my go to response in that situation.

Answer (score 2):

> It's ok/all right
>
> Don't worry about it.
>
> No harm done

If you don't want to simply say *everything is fine* and want to show  what the person did  actually hurt alittle bit but still you want to be polite, I think you can go like this

> I appreciate your apology.
>
> I hear you.
>
> I accept your apology.

*'I hear you'* can be used especially when you're in no mood to discuss it probably because what happened really was a bummer.