# American equivalent of "no worries"?

Tags: phrase-usage, idioms, conversation

From my understanding, "no worries" is one way to reply a polite apology. For example, it's something I can say when someone tells me that he or she would be late because of something unexpected. However, I just learned that people don't say it in the States so I wonder what's an alternative way to answer such an apology?

Comment: 'No problem', I expect. Both are informal.

Comment: *"I just learned that people don't say it in the States"* - this is not correct.  [People do say it in the US, and it is becoming more common.](https://qz.com/192475/how-no-worries-became-a-thing-surfers-crocodile-dundee-and-the-lion-king/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to answer the apology](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/85890/how-to-answer-the-apology)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a mistake to say that people in the USA *don't* say "no worries", but it is typically thought of as an Australian English idiom. I'm a native British English speaker, and the same applies here - some people do say it, but it is thought of as being of Australian origin.

"No problem", and derivations of it, are probably the most common equivalent in US and British English. It is worth noting that a pseudo-Spanish derivation "*no problemo*" is so commonly said by English speakers that it has found its way into [dictionaries](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/no-problemo).

I would go as far as to say that "no worries" also captures a relaxed attitude often associated with Australians (which may well be a generalisation, but not a negative one). The use of this phrase also conveys that kind of attitude, in much the same way as is intended when English speakers borrow similarly relaxed phrases like "*mañana*", "*c'est la vie*", or "*que sera sera*" from other languages.

Comment: a pseudo-Spanish derivation "no problemo" - this could lead me to murder.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey that definition is straight from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_problem#No_problemo

Comment: I just hate those jokey sayings. I once heard someone say 'no problemito'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey C'est normale.

Comment: I think "no worries" is becoming more popular both in the USA and the UK.